# Wordpress theme - support plugins Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, themes

I have developed simple Wordpress theme an year ago and now I am trying to use Ninja Forms with it and I am realizing that the plugin is not able to add its Javascript to my theme.

I was trying to switch my site to default theme and Ninja Forms started to work so problem must be in my theme. I am not really sure where should I start to finding problem so I am seeking help here - I am not really Wordpress theme developer so I have little experiences.

I have `wp_head()` in my `header.php` and I am already including my scripts in `functions.php` by registering them with `wp_register_script()` and then including them with `wp_enqueue_script()` like this:

```
function scripts_with_jquery()
{
    wp_register_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
    wp_register_script( 'mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
    wp_register_script( 'parseuri', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.parseuri.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
    wp_register_script( 'loader', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.loader.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'parseuri' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'loader' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_with_jquery' );
```

That's it. I am not really sure if there is something else what should I do so scripts from other plugins will load so if anybody has something on his/her mind please help me resolve this issue.

Just in case here is some code I am tweaking `wp_head()` with so please let me know if you spot some error there:

```
function twentyten_remove_recent_comments_style() {
    global $wp_widget_factory;
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $wp_widget_factory->widgets['WP_Widget_Recent_Comments'], 'recent_comments_style' ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyten_remove_recent_comments_style' );

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I just realized that I was missing `wp_footer()` call - [this article helped](http://www.sitepoint.com/including-javascript-in-plugins-or-themes/).